# Cannot package APK after adding expo to react-native project

Tags: android, react-native, babeljs, expo

I've been developing a react native app for a while now and I was able to generate APKs using the `./gradlew assembleRelease` command. I recently added expo to the project as I replaced the react-native-camera library with expo-camera. My debug builds are running fine (using `react-native run-android`). But when I try to package the app into an APK, I'm met with the following error:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease


> Configure project :app

Installing unimodules:
 unimodules-core@6.0.0 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/@unimodules/core
 unimodules-react-native-adapter@5.7.0 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter
 expo-application@2.4.1 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/expo-application
 expo-camera@9.1.1 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/expo-camera
 expo-constants@9.3.5 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/expo-constants
 expo-error-recovery@1.4.0 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/expo-error-recovery
 expo-file-system@9.3.0 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/expo-file-system
 expo-font@8.4.0 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/expo-font
 expo-image-loader@1.3.0 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/expo-image-loader
 expo-keep-awake@8.4.0 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/expo-keep-awake
 expo-linear-gradient@8.4.0 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/expo-linear-gradient
 expo-location@10.0.0 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/expo-location
 expo-permissions@10.0.0 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/expo-permissions
 expo-secure-store@9.3.0 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/expo-secure-store
 expo-splash-screen@0.8.1 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/expo-splash-screen
 expo-sqlite@8.5.0 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/expo-sqlite
 expo-updates@0.4.1 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/expo-updates
 unimodules-app-loader@1.4.0 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/unimodules-app-loader
 unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface@5.4.0 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface
 unimodules-camera-interface@5.4.0 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/unimodules-camera-interface
 unimodules-constants-interface@5.4.0 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/unimodules-constants-interface
 unimodules-face-detector-interface@5.4.0 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/unimodules-face-detector-interface
 unimodules-file-system-interface@5.4.0 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/unimodules-file-system-interface
 unimodules-font-interface@5.4.0 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/unimodules-font-interface
 unimodules-image-loader-interface@5.4.0 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/unimodules-image-loader-interface
 unimodules-permissions-interface@5.4.0 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/unimodules-permissions-interface
 unimodules-sensors-interface@5.4.0 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/unimodules-sensors-interface
 unimodules-task-manager-interface@5.4.0 from /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/unimodules-task-manager-interface

> Task :react-native-video:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
warning: the transform cache was reset.
                 Welcome to React Native!
                Learn once, write anywhere


TypeError: (intermediate value).eachMapping is not a function
error index.js: (intermediate value).eachMapping is not a function. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
    at toBabelSegments (/Users/anil/testing/node_modules/metro/node_modules/metro-source-map/src/source-map.js:167:46)
    at /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/metro/src/JSTransformer/worker.js:425:15
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/anil/testing/node_modules/metro/src/JSTransformer/worker.js:75:24)
    at _next (/Users/anil/testing/node_modules/metro/src/JSTransformer/worker.js:95:9)
    at /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/metro/src/JSTransformer/worker.js:100:7
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/anil/testing/node_modules/metro/src/JSTransformer/worker.js:92:12
    at JsTransformer._minifyCode (/Users/anil/testing/node_modules/metro/src/JSTransformer/worker.js:437:7)

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1m 4s
93 actionable tasks: 93 executed
```

I tried the following before running release:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

but that does not seem to fix the issue.

When I use Android Studio and use the menu option Build -> Build Bundle -> Build APK(s), I get the debug build of the app (the one that looks for the react-native server). Currently, in our distribution setup, I can only use APKs. App Bundle is not supported yet. I also tried updating the `metro-react-native-babel-preset` version to the latest. That did not seem to make any difference either.

Comment: this doesn't look related to having added expo-camera, this looks like an issue with the babel config in your project

Comment: @brentvatne Could you please suggest a possible solution to this? I'm currently having this issue and i don't know what to do

Comment: try this: https://expo.fyi/manual-debugging